# Makes a typical driver totally pucker

Tags: word-meaning

One of the examples of the word Pucker (noun) in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pucker is "Northern California’s Rubicon Trail—one of the most iconic and difficult off-road routes in the world—makes a typical driver totally pucker." I don't understand (1) the real meaning of "pucker" in this sense and (2) why "totally" (assumed as an adverb) is placed in front of a noun. Could you shed some light please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you think it's a noun? Have you consulted any dictionaries?

Comment: The example is presented under the "Recent Examples on the Web: Noun" session. Is it not a noun, @LucianSava?

Comment: Stan: Some helpful reading, on meta: [Are thanks on answers unnecessary?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/are-thanks-for-the-answers-unnecessary).

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a colourful phrase from the lead paragraph of a current (2018) US magazine about off-road driving.

**To pucker** is a verb meaning to wrinkle.  Here it might politely mean **purse his lips** (as if eating something sour) but given its context, is much more likely to mean what commenter (thanks!) described as "anal contraction caused by fear", per Urban Dictionary.

> OED: 1. intransitive. To gather or contract into creases, small folds, or bulges; to become drawn together into wrinkles or corrugations.

The adverb **totally** here just is emphasis.

Comment: I think pucker here has to do with anal contraction caused by fear.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey not slang I knew, you are surely correct, answer edited.

Comment: And to explicitly answer the question, *pucker* is a verb and *totally* is an adverb.

Comment: "Pucker Factor - A measure of the stressfulness of a situation, determined by the amount of muscle tension registered in one’s rectum. " [Naval Terminology, Jargon and Slang](https://www.hazegray.org/faq/slang2.htm). It's also in later Partridge editions.